# Why are intents resolved differently?

Tags: android-intent

As you all know after declaring intent filters in the manifest file to suit your needs using things like 'android.intent.action.MAIN', 'android.intent.action.VIEW', 'android.intent.action.EDIT', these are resolved. The thing is, attributes like 'android.intent.action.MAIN', 'android.intent.action.EDIT' are resolved as 'android.app.action.action.MAIN', 'android.app.action.EDIT', changing intent part to app. But the attributes like 'action.intent.action.VIEW' doesn't change after it is resolved. I don't understand why and this kind of difference happens. I've searched on the web for answers but still can't find the explanation for this. Could please someone tell me what makes this difference?